# FEATURED and BEST SELLING product show on homepage more than listed in category

Tags: magento-1.9, flat-catalog

[image]

[image]

Previously i am using without  "Use Flat Catalog Category
" so, everything is correct , but due to slow performance o moved on Use Flat Catalog Category, problem is started from here. now FEATURED and BEST SELLING product homepage block have more than 1k product on homepage. 
Please help me .
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: have you rebuilt the flat indexes and cleared the cache after your changes?